# How to use method of vue2-filters inside of computed

Tags: vuejs2

In my  @vue/cli 4.0.5 app I installed vue2-filters and it works ok in templates,
but when I try to use in in computed method I got error:

```
this.pluralize is not a function"
```

In my component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'
Vue.use(Vue2Filters)

...

export default {

    name: 'CategoryDetails',
    mixins: [appMixin, Vue2Filters.mixin],

    ...
    computed: {
        getRelatedTasksHeaderTitle: function () {          // ERROR HERE and Similar error and without "this."
            return ' Has ' + this.relatedTasks.length + ' ' + this.relatedTasks.length | this.pluralize(['task', 'tasks'])
        },
```

"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue2-filters": "^0.8.0",

How correctly ?

Comment: Have you tried `this.$options.filters.pluralize()` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks! But with line :              return (' Has ' + this.relatedTasks.length + ' ') + ( this.relatedTasks.length | this.$options.filters.pluralize(['task', 'tasks']) )
I got result line  : "Has 2 2", but not "Has 2 tasks" as I expected, if this.relatedTasks.length == 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the filter as a function, providing the value to be filtered as its 1st argument:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'
Vue.use(Vue2Filters)

...

export default {

    name: 'CategoryDetails',
    mixins: [appMixin, Vue2Filters.mixin],

    ...
    computed: {
        getRelatedTasksHeaderTitle: function () 
        {
            return ' Has ' + 
              this.relatedTasks.length + 
              ' ' + 
              this.$options.filters.pluralize(this.relatedTasks.length, ['task', 'tasks'])
        },
```

Comment: Thanks! But could you please give a link where in vuejs  this.$options described ? Is this decision specific only for vue2-filters ?

Comment: The syntax with a vertical line (the "pipeline" symbol) works **only** in templates - in JavaScript code the "pipeline" symbol actually means "bitwise logical OR". To call a filter from JavaScript code you have to call the function for the filter - if it is not an inline function you can just import it in your component and call it directly. If it is inline or 3rd party - you can access it only through `$options.filters` https://dev.to/flowck/accessing-vue-global-filters-inside-component-methods-1pai